# Firefox very slow

Tags: firefox

I am running Firefox 23.0 on Ubuntu 13.04 (64-bit) and it is a real pain at the best of times.

It takes around 45 seconds to have a usable window after I click on Firefox in the launcher: 15-20 seconds for a window to show, and then 25-30 seconds of a blank window before it is usable.

Many web-pages that I use regularly cause Firefox to freeze up for around 10-20 seconds before it is usable again.

I first thought there was just a bug in Firefox 21/22, so I waited a few versions before speaking up. I installed a clean Ubuntu 13.04 a month or two ago.

In comparison, LibreOffice and Gimp are both usable within 10 seconds after I click on them. The problem does not, therefore, seem to be hardware-related.

I would appreciate any help! Just please don't tell me to switch to Chrome/ium. Firefox worked perfectly on Ubuntu 12.10 before I clean-installed Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it appears the PrivacyChoice.org TrackerBlock plugin seems to be the culprit.

The first thing I did when installing was to protect myself from the NSA and advertisers. But, now when I started Firefox in Safe Mode, it was super-fast, as one would expect from a 64-bit system, even if my hardware can be slow sometimes.

I use other blocking plugins now instead. Be warned!

Comment: Just a side note: Blocking cookies and cleaning HTML5 storage and flash cookies might help for specific advertising companies. But you won't get very far with it for "protecting [your]self from the NSA".

Comment: I know that this answer solved your question, however it is not general enough to apply to every situation. Therefore I feel you were wrong to award yourself the answer.

Comment: It was that specific plugin that caused problems. It was not a general problem, and only applies to people using that specific plugin. It is a specific answer to a specific problem.

Answer (score 16):

Bitten by the same problem. To make a long story short, open tools->add-ons manager, and disable Ubuntu Firefox Modifications. Back to fast browsing.

Comment: disabling all ubuntu integration extensions totally made it for me.

Comment: This did not work for me. I disabled the PrivacyChoice.org plugin and suddenly Firefox was lightning-fast.

Comment: Wow! That's like night and day. Those add-ons made Firefox almost unusable for me.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU - Its so good to be able to use the browser again!

Comment: worked for me on ubuntu 15.10 + ublock origin, don't understand somebody closed this

Answer (score 6):

try this,
type "about:config" on address bar> enter
search and change/toggle by right clicking on item as-

- network.http.pipelining > Make it True
- network.http.pipelining.maxrequests > Make it higher (i set 34)
- network.http.proxy.pipelining > Make it True
- network.dns.disableIPv6 > Make it True

my firefox on netook system got really normal as on windows