# Firefox terribly slow on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, firefox

I tried all the solutions offered here:

- [Mozilla Firefox terribly slow on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459271/mozilla-firefox-terribly-slow-on-ubuntu-14-04)
- [Firefox 43.0.4 on Ubuntu 15.10 incredibly slow to load pages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721315/firefox-43-0-4-on-ubuntu-15-10-incredibly-slow-to-load-pages)

Is there a solution given the the environment below?:

- Firefox browser version: 51.0.1 (64 bits)
- Operatin system: Ubuntu 16.04.2 (64 bits)

Note that the 2 other browsers available on my machine work just fine (not slow)

Comment: What are your hardware specs?

Comment: Slow how? Network speed is slow? Or the browser consumes too much memory and acts sluggish? Your question does not clearly say. Also, post your specs.

Comment: Other browsers work fine,  I have a performant computer, I do not see I do not see a hardware issue here.

Comment: @Billal As others said, please post your specs, then it will be much easier to help.

Comment: OP failure to respond with specifications as requesting makes question too broad and voting to close as such.

Answer (score 1):

Change your desktop-enviroment to something lighter.

Comment: I did this. And I'm currently running Xubuntu, which has an easy to get used-to interface.

Comment: @MarkYisri Yes, but changing an environment just for this issue is not the best option.

Comment: Ok.. You are right but otherwise you should do the standard cleaning of history, downloads and useless add-onns... Try looking up at your ram while you start firefox .. Probably you will see ubuntu running in about 250/300 mb and firefox alone takes other 250 mb .. An so firefox is our best browser but it is known to be heavy... Chrome might be faster.. All dependeds on your hardware that you haven't allready specified..